# Can someone please help me identify this plant? It's lived six years in just water. :)

Tags: identification, houseplants

[image][image]

Can someone please help me identify this house plant? It's lived in cups and water for six years and I love it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a rather sickly looking Sansevieria 'hahnii' -image of how its supposed to look here http://www.glasshouseworks.com/sansevieria-trifasciata-hahnii. Click on image 2 because I think that's the coloration yours has, although it's hard to tell because yours isn't showing much striation or variegation.

Its quite a feat to get this to survive in water all those years, but it would be so much healthier if you potted it up into potting soil in a pot with a drainage hole, one that's big enough to accommodate the roots, preferably without cramping them up too much.

Comment: And no added fertilizer in 6 years?  Huh...

Comment: @stormy the miracle of life, its amazing how life clings on against all the odds

Comment: No more a statement truer.

Answer (score 2):

It is a compact variation of the 'average' snake plant: Sansevieria trifasciata 'Hahnii' (bird's nest snake plant).

You can find a lot of information about this plant [here](https://plantcaretoday.com/snake-plant-sansevieria.html).